# Get a list of distinct max values

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a class TopRegion

```
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Year { get; set; }
public decimal? ParticipationPercentage { get; set; }
```

And a list of TopRegion

```
IList<TopRegion> TopRegions = new List<TopRegion>();
```

The list is populated with 200+ TopRegion, some with the same Year and different or same ParticipationPercentage. There are 14 unique years in total and what I want to do is populate a top list of sorts for each year. So, the TopRegion item with the highest ParticipationPercentage for year 1950, 1960, 1970, etc. and put them into this list

```
IList<TopRegion> TopRegionsByYear = new List<TopRegion>();
```

What is the best way to go about this? I thought it might be with LINQ, but my LINQ skills aren't sharp enough for this operation

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GroupBy` and `OrderByDescending`:

```
IList<TopRegion> TopRegionsByYear = TopRegions 
    .GroupBy(tr => tr.Year)
    .Select(yg => yg.OrderByDescending(tr => tr.ParticipationPercentage).First())
    .ToList()
```

By the way, why is `Year` a string and not an integer? You always have to parse it, for example if you wanted to order the list above chronologically:

```
IList<TopRegion> TopRegionsByYear = TopRegions 
    .GroupBy(tr => tr.Year)
    .Select(yg => yg.OrderByDescending(tr => tr.ParticipationPercentage).First())
    .OrderBy(tr => int.Parse(tr.Year))
    .ToList()
```

Comment: You're right, I went back into my code and corrected it so they are int now. The code works but for some reason I'm only getting 5 different years instead of the 14 that I have

Comment: @Ras: that's hard to answer because we don't see your data

Comment: Is there a smooth way to show you all of the data inside my TopRegions list? If it would help

Comment: @Ras - not sure if it is "smooth" enough for you, but maybe use the feature "Pinnable Properties" - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/pinnable-properties-debug-display-managed-objects-your-way/

Comment: @RandRandom: thanks for this, i did not know it